# Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_{n}$ if for all $n\ge 1$ $\{x_n\}$denotes a sequence of real numbers where $x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2}(x_n+\frac{5}{x_n})$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, recursion

> Also given
>
> Let x be a positive number.
>
> $x_{1}=\dfrac{1}{2}(x+\dfrac{5}{x})$, $x_{2}=\dfrac{1}{2}(x_1+\dfrac{5}{x_1})$

I have shown that for all $n\ge 1$, $\dfrac{x_n-\sqrt{5}}{x_n+\sqrt{5}}={\bigg(\dfrac{x-\sqrt{5}}{x+\sqrt{5}}}\bigg)^{2^{n}}$

But from here I get $x_n=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}\cdot 2 \cdot \bigg({\bigg(\dfrac{x-\sqrt{5}}{x+\sqrt{5}}}\bigg)^{2^{n}}+1\bigg)}{1-{\bigg(\dfrac{x-\sqrt{5}}{x+\sqrt{5}}}\bigg)^{2^{n}}}$

But from here how do I get $lim_{n\to \infty}x_{n}$

L'Hospital does not help me here as I think.

It is a **GREAT GRAND SHAME ON MYSELF** that I could not think of the problem in a simpler way.

I should edit this:

We know

$x_{n}=\dfrac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\dfrac{5}{x_{n-1}})$

$\implies \dfrac{1}{2}(x_{n-1}+\dfrac{5}{x_{n-1}})\ge \bigg(x_{n-1}\cdot \dfrac{5}{x_{n-1}} \bigg)^{1/2}$[By the A.M-G.M inequality]

$\implies x_n \ge \sqrt{5}$

Thus $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}x_{n}= \sqrt{5}$

Done!!I should die right now!!

Comment: This is a classical iterative technique for calculating square roots. The formula you have shown is the key (+1). First observe that $x_2>\sqrt5$ always, do you see why? Therefore we can as well assume that the sequence started from a number $x>\sqrt5$ (we always have the option to just leave $x_1$ out of the reckoning. But, if $x>\sqrt5$, then
$$0<\frac{x-\sqrt5}{x+\sqrt5}<1.$$ This means that you know the limit 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{x-\sqrt5}{x+\sqrt5}\right)^{2^n}\to ?$$ Then you should be able to deduce that $x_n\to\sqrt5$.

Comment: Actually it suffices to observe that $-1<(x-\sqrt5)/(x+\sqrt5)<1$ for all positive $x$, so you can scratch my suggestion to restart from $x_2$.

Comment: A more general exercise: Let $a$ and $x_0$ be positive real numbers. Define $(x_n)$ by $x_n=\frac{1}{2} (x_{n-1}+\frac{a}{x_{n-1}})$ .Then $x_n \rightarrow \sqrt{a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By induction we get easy that all $$x_i>0$$, so we Can use the $AM-GM$ inequality and we get
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(x_n+\frac{5}{x_n}\right)\geq \sqrt{x_n\cdot \frac{5}{x_n}}=\sqrt{5}$$

Comment: This is the cutest and the best proof I have ever seen. Shame on me ! And a million upvotes to you.

Answer (score 2):

Given $ \ x_{n+1}=\frac{1}{2} (x_n+\frac{5}{x_n} ) \\ $  ,.........(1)

Let $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=l \ $ , then $ \ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_{n+1}=l \ $

Hence taking limit $ \ n \to \infty \ $ of both sides of $ \ (1) \ $ , we get

$$ l=\frac{1}{2} (l+\frac{5}{l})  \\ \Rightarrow  2l^2=l^2+5 \\ \Rightarrow l^2=5 \\ \Rightarrow l=\sqrt 5 $$

Therefore,

$$ \lim_{n \to \infty} x_n=l \ =\sqrt 5 $$

Comment: Splendid proof !

Comment: This is only half of the proof.  This shows: **if** the limit exists and is positive, **then** the limit is $\sqrt{5}$.  The other half of the proof would be: the limit exists and is positive.